# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner here and i was working with some react course from udemy and while everything was working perfect and fine and all my files are double checked with the instructor by myself but at this point it is throwing an error which i'm unable to figure out.

the error is thrown as shown below.

```
 6 |    const transformedIngredients = Object.keys(props.ingredients)
   7 |    .map(igKey => {
   8 |        return [...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])].map((_, i) => {
>  9 |           return <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />;
     |                 ^  
  11 |        });
  12 |    });
```

burger.js

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Burger.css';
import BurgerIngredient from './BurgerIngredient/BurgerIngredient';

const burger = (props) => {
    const transformedIngredients = Object.keys(props.ingredients)
    .map(igKey => {
        return [...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])].map((_, i) => {
           return <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />;

        });
    });
    return (
    <div className ={classes.Burger}>
        <BurgerIngredient type="bread-top" />
       {transformedIngredients}
        <BurgerIngredient type="bread-bottom" />
    </div>
    );
};

export default burger;
```

the code is same as the instructor but throwing above error.

other two files are pasted below

burgerbuilder.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Auxy from '../../Hoc/Auxy'; 
import Burger from '../../components/Burger/Burger';

class BurgerBuilder extends Component {

    state = {
        ingredients: {
            salad: 1,
            bacon: 1,
            meat: 1,
            cheese: 2

        }
    }
    render() {
        return ( 
            <Auxy>
                 <Burger />
                <div>Build Controls </div>

            </Auxy>
        );
    }
}
export default BurgerBuilder;
```

burgeringredient.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classes from './BurgerIngredient.css';

class BurgerIngredient extends Component {
    render () {

        let ingredient = null;
        switch (this.props.type){
        case ('bread-bottom'):
        ingredient = <div className={classes.BreadBottom}></div>;
        break;
        case ('bread-top'):
        ingredient = (
            <div className={classes.BreadTop}>
            <div className={classes.Seeds1}></div>
            <div className={classes.Seeds2}></div>
            </div>
        );
        break;
        case ('meat'):
        ingredient =<div className={classes.Meat}></div>;
        break;
        case ('cheese'):
        ingredient =<div className={classes.Cheese}></div>;
        break;
        case ('bacon'):
        ingredient =<div className={classes.Bacon}></div>;
        break;
        case ('salad'):
        ingredient =<div className={classes.Salad}></div>;
        break;
        default:
        ingredient =null;
    }
    return ingredient;

    }
} 

BurgerIngredient.propTypes={
    type: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default BurgerIngredient;
```

Comment: Where was the error thrown from? How are you debugging this? Do you have a call stack?

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54881406/edit) any new info directly into the question, no need to answer in comments.

Comment: i had provided all information i saw on my screen so now you can check thank you in advance.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks.

Comment: Please console.log `Object.keys(props.ingredients)`, `igKey` and `props.ingredients[igKey])`

Comment: sorry, i didn't get you David Joos because if i tried to console log nothing is displayed instead of error in there.

Comment: If I may, in this file `burgerbuilder.js` you didn't put any **props** `ingredients` so the **const** `transformedIngredients` in `burger.js` will render nothing. By the way, in ES6, you can reduce `<div className={classes.Bacon}></div>` to `<div className={classes.Bacon} />` for example, good luck !
Also remove this const temporarily `transformedIngredients` and put `console.log(Object.keys(props.ingredients))` and tell us what it renders.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue!

in burgerbuilder.js make sure to return pass ingredients into the burger component:

```
             <Burger ingredients={this.state.ingredients} />
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who get this error, also check if you have declared your state in BurgerIngredients.js instead of BurgerBuilder.js

Thank me later.